# python error in addon "Load Obj Sequence as Shape Keys"

Tags: python, add-on

error in Python script?
The imports all load bbut no shape keys--on Mac -here is my error message--I really appreciate any help! G.E.

(line 59):

sknames = [sk.name for sk in target.data.shape_keys]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
script link follows:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwi5qY2yrOTNAhVF2D4KHU86DfAQFggvMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blenderinmotion.com%2Fresources%2Fio_obj_as_shapekey.py&usg=AFQjCNFNzLkGqWM1QGdP3-Qgdv8251JtsA&sig2=X319gVkvLZFd7O283UVzuQ&bvm=bv.126130881,d.dmo&cad=rja

Comment: I wrote this addon. I saw just saw you posted in the BlenderArtist thread, but for some reason I wasn't subscribed to it so I didn't get any alerts. Are you using the mac version of the script?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing to notice is that

```
target.data.shape_keys.key_blocks
```

is a null or empty object at the point of the error and thus the script cannot execute the for loop to fill the `sknames` object.

Upon looking into this further it seems the issue is with the file path that references the location of the obj files around line 56 (at least it did for me).

Replacing this:

```
for f in files:
    fp = spath[0] + "\\" + f
```

with this:

```
for f in files:
    fp = os.path.join(spath[0], f)
```

seemed to solve it for me.